# Converting 16 digit account number from char to numeric in sas

Tags: sas, character, numeric

Hi all Iam trying to convert an sixteen digit account number which is character to numeric in sas
Account_char = 123456789982635
So I used input(account_char , 16.)

Iam getting output of the numeric converted as 3.743554E14

Can someone help me where Iam going wrong .
I need output of the sixteen digit account number in numeric .

Comment: Why?  You do not want to do arithmetic with that field.  Also not all 16 digit strings can be exactly represented as numbers.The maximum integer that SAS can store exactly on Unix/Windows is 9,007,199,254,740,992.

Comment: Cause Iam using this in where condition wi Th other table which is of numeric type

Comment: Is the other table also a SAS dataset?  Do you know the maximum possible value that field could have?  And the maximum value currently in the dataset with a numeric value?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't have values so large that they cannot be uniquely stored as a number in SAS just use INPUT() or PUT() function to convert from string to number and the reverse.  Make sure to use a format other than the default BEST12. format to display the numbers so that all digits will print.

SAS Code Examples:

```
data table_w_num;
  set table_w_char;
  account_num = input(account_char,16.);
  format account_num 16.;
run;

data table_w_char;
  set table_w_num;
  account_char = left(put(account_num,16.));
run;
```

SQL examples using macro variables:

```
select account_char into :mvar1 from table_w_char;
select * from table_w_num where account_num = &mvar1;
select quote(strip(put(account_num,16.))) into :mvar2 from table_w_num;
select * from table_w_char where account_char = &mvar2;
```

SQL examples using joins

```
select * from table_w_num n inner join table_w_char c
  on n.account_num = input(c.account_char,16.)
;
select * from table_w_num n inner join table_w_char c
  on c.account_char = strip(put(c.account_num,16.))
;
```

If the character field has leading zeros use Z16. format instead of 16. format. The informat used does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted number has 15 digits. Not 16.

However, you're all good. Just the formating:

```
data _null_;
   Account_char = "123456789982635";
   Account_num  = input(Account_char, 15.);
   put Account_num= 15.;
run;
```

Comment: How can I use the character column in sql query in sas ?

Comment: Yes you can.  `Select input(account_char,16.) as account_num format=z16. from table`